# Angularjs And Laravel WebSockets

Tags: angularjs, apache, websocket

I am using **Angularjs** for frontend and **Laravel 5.1** for api's. All of it is running on **apache server**.
I have read that apache server is not a good choice for **websockets**.
What should i do next.?

Comment: Have you thought about integration with nginx? See here: https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/